# Issue setting permissions on an nginx temp folder

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am getting this error when executing a post request:

```
POST http://localhost/node/api/stickies 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.min.js:78
Object {data: "<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</ti…disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
", status: 500, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

so when I check nginx I see

```
2014/08/27 10:08:57 [crit] 56240#0: *2312 open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /node/api/stickies HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/node/"
```

yet when I go to this directory /usr/local/var/run/nginx and do ls -l I get

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody  admin  68 Aug 26 11:17 client_body_temp
drwx------  2 nobody  admin  68 Aug  6 14:44 fastcgi_temp
drwx------  2 nobody  admin  68 Aug  6 14:44 proxy_temp
drwx------  2 nobody  admin  68 Aug  6 14:44 scgi_temp
drwx------  2 nobody  admin  68 Aug  6 14:44 uwsgi_temp
```

I think this means that there are full permissions for everyone in client_body_temp? Yet I still see this error in nginx. Am I setting the permissions correctly? Is it referring to a different set of permissions?

Comment: Could it be that the `0000...02` file in `client_body_temp` already exists?

Comment: I can't find anything inside of client_body_temp. as if no files exist  in there.

Comment: Ah, I have a hunch... Are you on CentOS/RHEL/Ubuntu? Might you have SELinux or AppArmor running?

Comment: Do you have TrustedBSD on, then?

Comment: no Ive never heard of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I had to do was to set rwx permissions for every parent directors. so I did it for client_body_temp, nginx, run, and var. Once I tried to do it for local it wouldn't let me. for some reason I didn't need to  for this. I guess because this is the nginx "root"?